# Is there a document management system like this?

Tags: documentation, admin, system-administration, dms

1.server-client architecture. all users sync(submit or checkout) documents from one local server(linux server, not windows).

2.with windows and linux client. the client will save all documents synced from the server locally. So when the users goe to places where they can not connect to the server, they still can view and edit their own copy of documents.

1. users commit their changes, the dms solve the conflicts like "git" or "svn". but great and complicated version control system is not needed.
2. client should have  fulltext search features.

At last, i wonder what document management system do those system administrators use.

Thanks

Comment: no, it is too complicated and don't have an linux client, also can not use it offline.

Comment: I briefly search through Google, and found this: http://www.filehold.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i determine to use mailing list to store documents.
(1)we all members of our team can sync docs from server.
(2)we can keep docs in series, so easy to maintain
(3)we can find all clients all though those platforms, like linux,windows,mac os x etc